A conductor is floating in the air and it suddenly makes contact with the positive terminal of a battery. Does current not flow through the conductor?
Imagine opening up a defective parachute and finally catching a live wire while in the air . If, our body is the conductor floating in the air , then on touching the wire our body will have the same potential as the live wire and therefore we will not have a flow of electrons and hence current through the body and hence we won't get zapped right ?
Tell me if I am understanding it correctly.
Also the connecting end(hands) has the same potential as the wire, what about our legs?

Do birds on high voltage power lined get zapped? Of course they do not.

Yes you do not get zapped, and since you are a conductor, your feet are at the same potential, but be cautious of touching a tree near by.
